# Getting strange error when testing rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have very simple test:

```
    require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test "should not save user without name" do
    user = User.new
    assert_not user.save
  end

end
```

where i test that user should not be saved into DB if he doesnt have a name. But i am getting this error:

```
>rake test:units
    DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
    Run options: --seed 36717

    # Running:

    E

    Finished in 0.159182s, 6.2821 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

      1) Error:
    UserTest#test_should_not_save_user_without_name:
    NoMethodError: undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass
        test/models/user_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:UserTest>'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

UserDB :

```
    class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
      t.uuid :id, :primary_key => true
      t.string :user_name
      t.string :name, :null => false
      t.string :sur_name
      t.integer :phone
      t.string :email
      t.string :encrypted_password
      t.string :salt
      t.integer :age
      t.string :education
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

User Model:

```
    require 'bcrypt'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveUUID::UUID

    before_save :hash_new_password

    def hash_new_password
      @newPassword  = BCrypt::Password.create(self.encrypted_password)
      self.encrypted_password = @newPassword
    end
end
```

What have i done wrong? I am trying to folow this guide from rails website: [rails test](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html)

Comment: What is the definition of the User model ?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `assert user.save, false`? -- Nevermind I just found the corresponding documentation

Comment: @MrYoshiji assert user.save, false gives same error

Comment: @Rafal updated my question with model and db

Comment: what happens if you test `assert_not user.valid?`

Comment: It will validate and run the test, its like .save is not a valid function.